# Artifactiry migration from 4.0.2 to 7

Tags: artifactory

I migrated from an artifactory 4.0.2 to a 7.last suing method 1 suggested by https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-is-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-large-artifactory-instance-with-minimal-downtime/.
Now surfing into the new repository I see all definitions fof my repositories as well as all metadata, however I don't see any artifact content (e.g. jar files).
I copied all filestore content from the old to the instance.
What I missed ?
Tks

Answer (score 0):

From the scenario you've described, it appears to be an issue with the storage (filestore) configuration/connection.

**What do we need to check next?**

- If you have updated the filestore path as a part of the migration, update the path into the storage configuration file [binarystore.xml] in the Artifactory instance. Let's say, you have moved the data from one mount to another mount to use the data via the new Artifactory version 7.x, this step will help Artifactory to know where exactly it needs to look out for the binaries.
- The file will be present under $JFROG_HOME/etc/artifactory/ directory in the Artifactory 7.x version.

Comment: I didn't change anything and data were copied to $FROG_HOME/artifactory/var/data/filestore (the default, I think).

Comment: I didn't change anything during installation.
Data where copied to $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/data/filestore.
The only meaningfull informations in binarystore.xml are

    <config version="1">
        <chain template="file-system"/>
    </config>

Tks

Comment: The default filestore path for the 7.x versions of Artifactory is /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/artifactory/filestore. Please check if the binary folders are present in the corresponding location. Also, try to configure the binarystore.xml file with detailed mount details as described here. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/File+System+Binary+Provider#FileSystemBinaryProvider-What'sinthetemplate?